# Check whether two strings are anagrams

Tags: r, string, anagram

What is the most straightforward way to check whether two strings are anagrams? i.e. they share the same letters as well as number of occurrences of each these letters (and possibly other characters).

Something like this:

```r
s1 = "elbow"
s2 = "below"

is_anagram(s1, s2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```r
s1 = "elbow"
s2 = "below"

is_anagram <- function(s1, s2){
  s1_sorted <- sort(strsplit(s1, "")[[1]])
  s2_sorted <- sort(strsplit(s2, "")[[1]])
  identical(s1_sorted, s2_sorted)
}

#> is_anagram(s1, s2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I sucessfully used this function to find all the anagrams in a list of 3000 words by mapping it onto the word list

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
> do.call(identical,Map(function(x) sort(utf8ToInt(x)), list(s1, s2)))
[1] TRUE
```

---

If you want to generalize the case to ***more than two strings***, e.g.,

```
s1 <- "elbow"
s2 <- "below"
s3 <- "owlbe"
```

then we can try

```
> lst <- list(s1, s2, s3)

> all(apply(table(stack(Map(utf8ToInt, setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))))), 1, var) == 0)
[1] TRUE
```

or

```
> lst <- list(s1, s2, s3)

> m <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(Map(utf8ToInt, setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))))))

> identical(do.call(pmin, m), do.call(pmax, m))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve that:

```r
library(tidyverse)

s1 = "elbow"
s2 = "below"

is_anagram <- function(s1, s2){
  identical(str_split(s1, "") %>% table, str_split(s2, "") %>% table)
}

is_anagram(s1, s2)

#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add a faster solution then the given ones:

idea: every letter is connected to a prime and two strings share the same letters, if the product of the numbers connected to these letters is the same. This is because every number has a unambiguously prime factor relocation.

```
primes <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101)
names(primes) <- letters

is_anagram_primes <- function(s1,s2){
  prod(primes[strsplit(s1,"")[[1]]]) == prod(primes[strsplit(s2,"")[[1]]])
}
```

A little benchmark:

```
is_anagram_sorted <- function(s1, s2){
  s1_sorted <- sort(strsplit(s1, "")[[1]])
  s2_sorted <- sort(strsplit(s2, "")[[1]])
  identical(s1_sorted, s2_sorted)
}

is_anagram_map <- function(s1,s2){
  do.call(identical,Map(function(x) sort(utf8ToInt(x)), list(s1, s2)))
}

primes <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101)
names(primes) <- letters

is_anagram_primes <- function(s1,s2){
  prod(primes[strsplit(s1,"")[[1]]]) == prod(primes[strsplit(s2,"")[[1]]])
}

library(microbenchmark)

s1 = "elbow"
s2 = "below"
microbenchmark(
  is_anagram(s1,s2),
  is_anagram_primes(s1,s2),
  is_anagram2(s1,s2)
)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
                      expr    min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
        is_anagram(s1, s2) 68.718 120.2515 153.20684 136.7995 150.1125  28275.22 10000
 is_anagram_primes(s1, s2)  9.736  18.8655  41.80904  22.3940  26.9795 154388.28 10000
       is_anagram2(s1, s2) 93.732 168.0290 227.70756 192.5055 218.9020  81723.76 10000
```